# Microsoft Edge CSS text-align

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Is it only me or there is quite an annoying bug in Windows 10 Edge browser?

I have just realized that text-align isn't working as expected in Edge.

I have

```
<div style='text-align:justify;'>
<h3> This is a short text </h3>
<div class='small_box'>some content </div>
<div class='small_box'>some content </div>
<div class='small_box'>some content </div>
etc...
<div class='small_box'>some content </div>
</div>
```

This will normally produce make the child div justify inside the parent div, and the H3 (header) where the width is much lower than the width of the parent div to be aligned to the left, works on all browsers, but in Edge, the whole content of H3 is stretched to match the width of the parent, making distance between the letters very big.

I did some testing at it looks like it is only having this strange behaviour on certain html elements: headers (`h1,h2,h3`), `span` and `div`. If instead of a header I use a paragraph `<p>` then it displays as expected.

A temporary link can be seen [here](http://94.23.203.111/whitelabel/product_listing.php?module=smartphones) I will soon create a fiddler as well and update the link for future reference.

Am I right in saying this is a bug in the new browser released by Microsoft?

Comment: Sounds like it...`text-align:justify` certainly shouldn't stretch text characters. Can't test at the moment though. A brief JSfiddle Demo of this issue with your CSS would be helpful though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own stupidity.

I head an inherited property: `text-justify: distribute-all-lines` which I have omitted. Based on the definition of the property this will make the last line of a text to be stretched to the width of the parent. IE 9,10,11 only applied it if the text had multiple lines, but looks like Edge is applying it to the last line regardless if the last line is the first and only line at the same time.

Re-reading the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531172(v=vs.85).aspx)  I have to agree with the Edge behaviour, but this then raises the question why is it different in IE 9,10,11?

Never mind just another Microsoft quirk.

Closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

try using padding-left & right

```
 .box-div {    
   height: 80vh;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   padding-left: 10%;
   padding-right: 10%;
 }
```

[image]